# Apache Server Mac – Proxy Error

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I am simply trying to use the built in apache Server for Mac OS X Sierra, to view my websites using the http://localhost domain. When tailing my logs, I am getting the following errors:

```
max:ssl maxnelson$ ps -aef | grep httpd
0   571     1   0 Wed07PM ??         0:01.06 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/services/ACSServer.conf -E /var/log/apache2/services/ACSServer_error_log
70   572   571   0 Wed07PM ??         0:00.09 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/services/ACSServer.conf -E /var/log/apache2/services/ACSServer_error_log
0   574     1   0 Wed07PM ??         0:01.30 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70   582   574   0 Wed07PM ??         0:00.11 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70   583   574   0 Wed07PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70   584   574   0 Wed07PM ??         0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70   585   574   0 Wed07PM ??         0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70   586   574   0 Wed07PM ??         0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70  8282   574   0  7:09PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70  8296   574   0  7:10PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70  8297   574   0  7:10PM ??         0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
70  8298   574   0  7:10PM ??         0:00.01 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/Server/Web/Config/Proxy/apache_serviceproxy.conf -E /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
501 36371  8333   0  7:32PM ttys001    0:00.00 grep httpd


max:ssl maxnelson$ sudo apachectl -k restart
httpd not running, trying to start
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

max:ssl maxnelson$ tail -f /private/var/log/apache2/service_proxy_error.log
[Thu Jul 06 19:33:48.002767 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 582] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:34580 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Jul 06 19:33:48.002903 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 582] [client ::1:57056] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu Jul 06 19:33:58.266146 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 585] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:34580 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Jul 06 19:33:58.266260 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 585] [client ::1:57060] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Thu Jul 06 19:33:58.469431 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 584] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:34580 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Jul 06 19:33:58.469554 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 584] [client ::1:57061] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://localhost/d3-timeline-master/example
[Thu Jul 06 19:34:01.239357 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 8296] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:34580 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Jul 06 19:34:01.239655 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8296] [client ::1:57062] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://localhost/
[Thu Jul 06 19:34:21.082799 2017] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 8297] [client ::1:57066] AH01382: Request header read timeout
[Thu Jul 06 19:34:21.082797 2017] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 586] [client ::1:57065] AH01382: Request header read timeout
[Thu Jul 06 19:38:38.439198 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 583] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:34580 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Jul 06 19:38:38.439354 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 583] [client ::1:57179] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Thu Jul 06 19:38:39.539888 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 8298] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:34580 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Jul 06 19:38:39.540047 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 8298] [client ::1:57180] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: http://localhost/d3-timeline-master/example
```

Happy to provide more information, I've tried following every article and doing everything I could find online and have had no luck. Its perhaps worth mentioning that I generated a new self-signed certificate recently, and not sure if that could be affecting things as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may have an other process listening on port 80. Check it with the command `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`

Comment: Silly me. This was the exact cause of the issue I was experiencing. I would like to mark this as the correct answer to my question. I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, I turn my comment into an answer.

You may have an other process listening on port 80. Check it with the command `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`